# jQuery How to get Current Year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code to set Datepicker conditionally but keeps getting year 2026. I would like to set min/max value based on the value selected

```
 $("#FY").kendoDatePicker({
        depth: "decade",
        start: "decade",
        format: "yyyy"
    });

    var datepicker = $("#FY").data("kendoDatePicker");
    var $today = new Date();
    var $priorYear = new Date($today);
    var $currentYear = new Date($today);
    
    if (dataItem.Code === 'WO') {           
        $priorYear.setDate($today.getFullYear() - 1);     
        $currentYear.setDate($today.getFullYear());    
        var min = datepicker.min($priorYear);    
        var max = datepicker.max($currentYear);
    }

    if (dataItem.Code === 'MO') {                  
        $priorYear.setDate($today.getFullYear() - 2);
        $currentYear.setDate($today.getFullYear());
        var min = datepicker.min($priorYear);
        var max = datepicker.max($currentYear);
    }
```

If `WO` I would like to show 2019 and 2020, if `MO` show 2018,2019, 2020 but it showing `2026` in both cases

Comment: Are you making newDate(newDate)) ?

Comment: `$today.getFullYear()` and `$today.getFullYear() - 1` are giving right values .

Comment: @Swati Thanks!  you mean `var $priorYear = $today.getFullYear() - 1`?

Comment: Yes do like that and see onces .

Comment: @Swati  that didn't work for me

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/np5u40sm/1/) will give you some ideas how to achieve above .

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the Telerik Dojo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>        
  <h4>WO</h4>
  <input id="woPicker" value="" title="WO picker" />

  <h4>MO</h4>
  <input id="moPicker" value="" title="MO picker" />
   
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var today = new Date();

      $("#woPicker").kendoDatePicker({
        start: 'century',
        min: new Date(today.getFullYear() - 1, 0),
        max: new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 31)
      });

      $("#moPicker").kendoDatePicker({
        start: 'century',
        min: new Date(today.getFullYear() - 2, 0),
        max: new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 31)
      });
  });
  </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**WO** will show 2019-2020 or current year and the year before that. **MO** will show 2018, 2019, and 2020 or current year and the last two years before that.